# Is it possible to create navigation bar on Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I've been trying to create a navigation bar on Google Apps Script. When `onclick`, I want the navigation to show a certain page. I tried using a `onclick()` in anchor tag but it seems like the `onclick()` function doesn't work with anchor tag in Apps Script... Is there any other way for me to create navigation bar in Apps Script?

## Edit

Sorry I think I've confused you for the question.
I want to put a navigation bar in a standalone webapp, and I'm building the webapp using google appscript. But I have problem when I want to link pages (about, news) to the nav bar. for example, When I click the nav bar, it will shows this n-fde2z55pv56hs752i7fn5pz4auy44qtfz7bsfzi-0lu-script.googleuser… instead of the news page. I noticed that if I include onclick() in achor tag, it will redirect me to this link https://n-fde2z55pv56hs752i7fn5pz4auy44qtfz7bsfzi-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel#about.

I'll include my code below so that you can have a clear view on my problem:

Below is my code:

```
    ### HTML code ###

    <!-- language: lang-html -->
    
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a  href=#news onclick="openNews()">News</a>
        <a  href=#about onclick="openAbout()">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="aboutDisplay" class="aboutDisplay">
        <div class="container">
            <p>about page</p>
        </div>
    </div>

      <div style="display:none" id="newsDisplay" class="newsDisplay">
        <div class="container">
            <p>news page</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    ### Javascript ###
    function openAbout() {
        document.getElementById("aboutDisplay").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("newsDisplay").style.display = "none"; 
    }  

     function openNews() {
        document.getElementById("aboutDisplay").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("newsDisplay").style.display = "block"; 
    }
```

Comment: If you're talking about a dialog or webapp then yes you could put a navigation bar.  But it's not a google apps script question it's an html/css question.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] including the console messages

Comment: @Cooper Hi sorry for confusing you, yes I want to put a navigation bar in a standalone webapp, and I'm building the webapp using google appscript. But i have problem when I want to link pages (about, news) to the nav bar. for example, When I click the nav bar, it will shows this https://n-fde2z55pv56hs752i7fn5pz4auy44qtfz7bsfzi-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel#about instead of the news page.

Comment: @Rubén HI I'm adding it to my post already ^^

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly it's simple but it looks like a navbar to me.

gs:

```
function launchmydialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2'),'Test');
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      .topnav{height: 50px; width:90%;border:2px solid black;padding:5px;}
      a{margin:2px 5px;font-family:calibri;font-size:24px;text-decoration:none;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a  href=#news onclick="openNews()">News</a>
    <a  href=#about onclick="openAbout()">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
</div>
  <script>
     function openNews() {
       window.alert('You clicked openNews')
     }
     function openAbout() {
       window.alert('You clicked openAbout')
     }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Image of Dialog:

[image]