# How do I reference a support file in Google Apps project

Tags: html, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications

Is it possible to use a support file from within the apps script project as a source for `iframe` in another HTML.
I need to do this as a part of a Web App project in Google Apps Script.
Specifically I need it to work as a menu system which is the same across multiple pages, so that I don't have to repeat the same HTML code over and over again.

Better explained in a picture
[image]
Left side menu(buttons) stays the same across pages
[image]

Comment: You could accomplish that with [templated html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) and load the page server side prior to rendering.

Comment: Take some time now and learn to use scriplets.  It's worth knowing and can save you lots of work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish what you are looking (" I don't have to repeat the same HTML code over and over again") but using iframe is not the best way when working with Google Apps Script web applications.

First you have to decide if you want to handle your web application as a multipage or as simple page.

In any case you might find helpful to use templated HTML / scriptlets to pass the code from Google Apps Script `.html` files to your main html code. If you find yourself scripts hard to start with, then you might use other methods of the HTML Service

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html

Related

- [Use project Javascript and CSS files in a Google Apps Script web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11344167/1595451)

Recent related question (no answers at this time, but with comments)

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML as sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54071341/1595451)
- [Is it possible to create navigation bar on Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67643854/1595451)
- [how to connect a navigation bar (<nav>) with HTML files in google appscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68959857/1595451)